# How to subtract dates of two column in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql

Please go through this edited table.

[image]

You can assume order_header_key as order no.

I want to get the list of order nos whose current status is 3 and previous status was 2, and the  status date(status3)-status date(2) <=3 days for that order

in the following table 
for order no-1  'date(status 3)' - 'date(status 2) = 20 OCT - 19 OCT 
which is less than 3 days--> So valid order

but for order no 3  'date(status 3)' - 'date(status 2)' = 30 OCT - 24 OCT
which is more than 3 days so invalid order

order no 2 in invalid since the statuses are 3 and 1 , 2 is missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming an order can't have more than one entry per order_no/status combination, you could join two subqueries:

```
SELECT s3.order_no
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   orders
        WHERE  status = 3) s3
JOIN   (SELECT *
        FROM   orders
        WHERE  status = 2) s2 ON s3.order_no = s2.order_no AND 
                                 s3.status_date - s3.status_date <= 3
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your response, I just edited the question.. an order's statuses will be stored in the database against the date, it is something like

Comment: Hey thanks for your response, I just edited the question.. an order's statuses will be stored in the database against the date, it is something like

Comment: Hey thanks for your response, I just edited the question.. an order's statuses will be stored in the database against the date, for example order no 1 had the status--order created on 18th then order shipped on 19th and delivered on 20th

Answer (score 3):

Use `lag()`:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*,
             lag(o.status_date) over (partition by o.order_no order by o.status_date ) as prev_sd,
             lag(o.status) over (partition by o.order_no order by o.status_date) as prev_status
      from orders o
     ) o
where prev_status = 2 and status = 3 and
      (status_date - prev_sd) <= 3;
```

Comment: `order by` is mandatory in the analytic clause for `lag()` (both for obvious logical reasons and required by syntax rules); without it, the query will not compile.

Comment: @mathguy . . . Thanks.  I just accidentally left it out.

Comment: One small question, If I want to get the date difference between two other statuses(say status 3 and 1) how do I do it?

Comment: because in lag order by is used so it gets only the previous record, how to specifically choose records which meet certain conditions? In my case i want to get records wrt their statuses

Comment: @NagarajB . . . That is a very different question, which should be asked separately.  This question is pretty clearly about a record of status 3 following a record of status 2.  You need to be very clear whether the statuses can be repeated and include appropriate sample data.

Comment: I was not aware of this lag function so

Answer (score 2):

Analytic functions (`lag()` in this case) allow you to avoid joins and/or subqueries, and may (and often will) be much faster.

```
with
--   begin test data; not part of the solution
     orders ( order_no, status, status_date ) as (
       select 1, 1, to_date('18-OCT-16', 'DD-MON-YY')from dual union all
       select 1, 2, to_date('19-OCT-16', 'DD-MON-YY')from dual union all
       select 1, 3, to_date('20-OCT-16', 'DD-MON-YY')from dual union all
       select 1, 1, to_date('20-OCT-16', 'DD-MON-YY')from dual union all
       select 1, 3, to_date('23-OCT-16', 'DD-MON-YY')from dual union all
       select 1, 2, to_date('24-OCT-16', 'DD-MON-YY')from dual union all
       select 1, 1, to_date('30-OCT-16', 'DD-MON-YY')from dual       
     ),
--   end test data; solution is the word "with" from above, plus the query below     
     prep ( order_no, status, status_date, prev_status, prev_status_date) as (
       select order_no, status, status_date,
              lag(status) over (partition by order_no order by status_date),
              lag(status_date) over (partition by order_no order by status_date)
       from   orders
     )
select order_no
from   prep
where  status = 3 and prev_status = 2 and prev_status_date - status_date <= 3
;


ORDER_NO
--------
       1
```